Keyboard Animation Issue in Swift UI with iOS 15: Animating from the Right Instead of Bottom
I'm developing an app using Swift UI on iOS 15 and encountering a peculiar issue with keyboard presentation. When transitioning to a new screen, I programmatically set focus to a TextField with a delay of 0.35 seconds, which triggers the keyboard to appear. However, the animation of the keyboard starts from the right side of the screen instead of sliding up from the bottom as usual.

Here's the code snippet I'm using:
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.35) {
    self.isFocused = true
}

Minimal reproducible example.
If I increase the delay to 0.6 seconds, the keyboard animates correctly from the bottom. But, a delay of 0.6 seconds is too long from a user experience perspective.
Is there any way to ensure that the keyboard animates from the bottom with a delay of 0.35 seconds? Any insights or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

Please show a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce the issue.
